# Lint error - unexpected string concatenation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lint

```
render() {
    const { a, b } = this.props;
    if (// some condition // )
    window.location.assign('/v2#/org/' + a + '/support')}
}
```

For the line `window.location.assign('/v2#/org/' + orgId + '/support')}` I get the lint error - unexpected string concatenation.

How to prevent this from happening ?

Comment: See the lint rule definition for some tips and rationale: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use template strings wrapped by " ` " (back tick/grave accent).

```js
window.location.assign(`/v2#/org/${orgId}/support`)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use string interpolation instead:

```js
render() {
    const { a, b } = this.props;
    if (// some condition // )
    window.location.assign(`/v2#/org/${a}/support`)}
}
```